# Role based authentication setting to defaultUrl in web.config in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application contains the roles "Admin" and "Users". How can I provide web.config setting for "users" with one default URL & "admin" with another default URL in web.config file.

My current web.config file code :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="/Welcome.aspx" loginUrl="/LogIn.aspx" >              
    </forms>        
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />      
</authorization>
```

My aspx.cs code under login with condition :

```
if (res =="USER") 
{
    Details det = new Details();
    int id = det.UserId(Email, Passwor);
    Label2.Text = id.ToString();
    Session["ID"] = Label2.Text;
    string name = det.UserName(Email, Passwor);
    Label3.Text = name;
    Session["Name"] = Label3.Text;
    Session["Role"] = TextBox1.Text;
     Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");
}
if (res =="ADMIN")
{
    FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(Email,true);
    //Response.Redirect("admin_page.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Not positive, but I don't think it's possible. Use redirect as you were, or show/hide a link to admin page if the user is admin.

Comment: @wazz , But I heard we are having the role based authentication. Wasn't it related to this ?

Comment: Really not sure. Wait for other feedback.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible via the webConfig file. The role-based authentication means you can use user's role to authorize user access to any actions. If you want to use webConfig to config the default address of each role, you can use your own define settings in webConfig. Please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx.